# Working with files (Storing array of strings) Android

Tags: android, arrays, file

I'm new in android programming and I have a problem.

I can't find how to create and store data in file.

I need to create a file (non text file) that will store array of strings
(example: Array{Nick, James, Director, 005001235NICK JAMES}.

I know how this work in delphi and I could do it in few minutes, but with android I'm not familiar jet. Can anyone help me?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: what do you mean by *(non text file)*

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a text file to store your arrays? If you really want to store your arrays in a binary file format, you could look into using a container class that implements the Java Serializable interface. With this you can write your classes to file, and read a file into your container/array class. The Android page on the serializable interface recommends the use of json text files. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 4):

You might find `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` and **`java.io.File`** useful. Before any writing is possible, your manifest must include an appropriate permission decleration. To write to the external storage, use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is a sample code that uses `java.io.File` to write a bitmap to file:

```
private void writeBitmapToFile(Bitmap bmp, File file) {
    try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```